# PickerView selectedValue anyObject returns nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to return the selectedValue of the UIPickerView called picker. The problem is that it always returns nil whatever i do. How come is this?

```
let done: ActionStringDoneBlock = {(picker: ActionSheetStringPicker!, selectedIndex: NSInteger!, selectedValue : AnyObject!) in
   prinln(selectedValue)    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is unwrapping a `NSInteger` in done Block, try to change `NSInteger!` to `NSInteger` and problem will be fixed.

```
let done: ActionStringDoneBlock = {(picker: ActionSheetStringPicker!, selectedIndex: NSInteger, selectedValue : AnyObject!) in
println(selectedValue)
```

}